# Colouring the next character using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, string, char

In the following simple piece of code all I am trying to do is colour any two characters based on certain conditions. the code is working fine except that the next character gets repeated twice. It is as follows:

```js
var myString = "Eagles are birds of prey.";
var newText = "";

for (var i = 0; i < myString.length; i++) {
  var char = myString.charAt(i);
  var nextChar = myString.charAt(i + 1);

  if (char == "E" && nextChar == "a") {
    newText += "<span class='clrRed'>" + char.concat(nextChar) + "</span>";
  } else if (char == "e") {
    newText += "<span class='clrGreen'>" + char + "</span>";
  } else {
    newText += char;
  }

}
document.getElementById('view').innerHTML = newText;
```

```css
#view {
  font-size: 28px;
}

.clrRed {
  color: red;
}

.clrGreen {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="view"></div>
```

Your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your are considering two characters, you need to increase the `i` inside that condition to directly move to the next one and avoid the duplication:

```js
var myString = "Eagles are birds of prey.";
var newText = "";

for (var i = 0; i < myString.length; i++) {
  var char = myString.charAt(i);
  var nextChar = myString.charAt(i + 1);

  if (char == "E" && nextChar == "a") {
    newText += "<span class='clrRed'>" + char.concat(nextChar) + "</span>";
    i++; /*added this*/
  } else if (char == "e") {
    newText += "<span class='clrGreen'>" + char + "</span>";
  } else {
    newText += char;
  }

}
document.getElementById('view').innerHTML = newText;
```

```css
#view {
  font-size: 28px;
}

.clrRed {
  color: red;
}

.clrGreen {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="view"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick response. You saved me a lot of head scratching.

Answer (score 0):

The described behavior is caused by a simple logical error: When you get to the "E" followed by an "a" you add "Ea" in read to `newText`. The next letter in your loop however is the "a" from your original text which gets also added to `newText` which results in a duplicated "a". There a several possible solutions to this problem:
First solution is to add `i++` after `newText += "<span class='clrRed'>" + char.concat(nextChar) + "</span>";`.
The second solution is to add an if after your last else to check if the character is an "a" which follows an "E". This could be done like so:

```
...} else if(char == 'a' && myString.charAt(i-1)=='E') {
  newText += char;
}
```

Comment: Your explanation is much appreciated. Very helpful indeed.